# How can i get a string from a paragraph using regex?

Tags: regex

I was looking at some regex to get a string from a paragraph, where I could pass a string or a phrase to get the next string to it.

An example is, where I would like to get the word `people` from the following paragraph where `seat one to eight` is next to it

> A car is a wheeled motor vehicle used for
>   transportation. Most definitions of car say they run primarily on
>   roads, `seat one to eight` people, have four tires, and mainly transport
>   people rather than goods.

Another example is, I would like to return the string `Ksh200.00` from the paragraph below by getting the word next to the phrase `shop and bought`

> The boy went to the `shop and bought` Ksh200.00 worth of milk and wnt
>   home

I just want to get a string that is next to the `phrase or string` that I can pass to the regex. I have tried but no luck, please help if it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with positive lookbehinds.

For the second example (first one is the same), lookbehind and taking next string without spaces:

```
(?<=shop and bought )[^\s]+
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/0tjcma/1)

Comment: `[^\s]` can also be written as `\S`.